# ComboBox.setModel inserting array as single item

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a GUI set up with three combo boxes where a selection from combobox 1 (comboRole) should then populated combobox 2 (comboClass) and so on. I have gotten the second combobox to populate, however all the items in the array are being treated as a single item so only the top level item in the array is selectable. I have a feeling it is something to do with how I am implementing the `.setModel`, but I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
    {
        String selectedRole = (String) comboRole.getSelectedItem();
        if ("Tank".equals(selectedRole)){
            comboClass.removeAllItems(); //cleans out any data currently in comboClass
            comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(TankClass)); //populating only top level item 
            //entire array is being treated as a single item.
        }
        else if ("Healer".equals(selectedRole)){
            comboClass.removeAllItems();
            comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(HealerClass));
        } 
        else if ("Caster".equals(selectedRole)){
            comboClass.removeAllItems();
            comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(CasterClass));
        }
        else if ("Damage".equals(selectedRole)){
            comboClass.removeAllItems();
            comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(DpsClass));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see why you have `comboClass.removeAllItems()`, since setting the model should be all that you need to do to remove all items and fill it with new items. Otherwise I don't see the source of your bug in the code you've posted.

Comment: Or you could ignore my comment. Your call.

Comment: i apologize this is my first post on StackOverflow and i was expected to get an email notifying me about any comments. thank you for your input though. comboClass.removeAllItems() was a reduancy i though id add to make sure that the box was clean before adding the items. as for the bug, i found a way to work around it using a while loop but im still not sure why setModel is adding all items in the array as a single item.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working either and suspect that the problem is not in the code you've posted but lies elsewhere in your program.

Comment: I was able to Resolve the issue. The problem was that i was using an ActionListener when i should have been using a ItemListener for state change

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is that An ActionListener Runs each time any combobox is secteded creating multipule instances of the arrays in the combo boxes. the Resolution Is to use a ItemListener for each Combobox so that it only adds the desiered array after that box has an item selected. also when using the ItemListener the `comboClass.removeAllItems` is needed to clean out the array for when a change in selection is made else just changing the model has a tendency to cause the previous array to stack on top of the new one.

```
        ItemListener roleListener = new ItemListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)                    
           {

               String selectedRole = (String) comboRole.getSelectedItem();


                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                        {
                            if ("Tank".equals(selectedRole))
                            {
                                comboClass.removeAllItems(); // removes previous selection from combobox
                                comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(TankClass)); //populates comboClass with Selection

                            }
                            else if ("Healer".equals(selectedRole))
                            {
                                comboClass.removeAllItems();
                                comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(HealerClass));
                            } 
                            else if ("Caster".equals(selectedRole))
                            {                
                                comboClass.removeAllItems();
                                comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(CasterClass));
                            }
                            else if ("Damage".equals(selectedRole))
                            {                
                                comboClass.removeAllItems();
                                comboClass.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(DpsClass));
                            }


                        }
           }

    };
```